# How to schedule cognos report dynamically to different emails

Tags: email, cognos

I'm using congos analytics to schedule report to different emails dynamically according to different report types.

I'm exploring the bursting report features below but i found it only allows to links two queries ( data to be sent, and recipient list) together, however in my case the data to be sent is a whole report that is made of different queries. How can I make it happen?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_cr_rptstd_modrep_set_burst_options.html#cr_rptstd_modrep_set_burst_options

Comment: Define "report type".  Why wouldn't these be separate reports?

Comment: @dougp sorry, report_type is a parameter in my cognos report which has data the data that needs to be sent out to users. when report_type  is differnt, it will generate diferent content . In a database i have a table that contains 2 columns, ie report_type and email address. I want cognos to generate different data and use different email address according to different report type

Comment: @dougp, so far i already have create the report which accepts prompted parameter and generate report accordingly ( it conssits multiple report in in ), but i dont know the part which requires to link to the right email

Comment: That's bursting.  Read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option. You'll need to be careful crafting your grouping to be only for bursting. You won't want it to affect the layout of the report.

Queries:

- Grouping - for the container
- Email - for bursting
- Others - feeding your visible report objects

Instructions:

1. Add a repeater to the page
2. Put the visible report objects in the repeater
3. Set the *Master detail relationship* for every object
4. Set the busting info

Here is an example using the *GO sales (query)* package:

```
<report xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/14.3/" useStyleVersion="11.4" expressionLocale="en-us">
    <drillBehavior/>
    <layouts>
        <layout>
            <reportPages>
                <page name="Page1">
                    <style>
                        <defaultStyles>
                            <defaultStyle refStyle="pg"/>
                        </defaultStyles>
                    </style>
                    <pageBody>
                        <style>
                            <defaultStyles>
                                <defaultStyle refStyle="pb"/>
                            </defaultStyles>
                        </style>
                        <contents>
                            <block>
                                <contents>
                                    <repeater name="Repeater1" refQuery="country">
                                        <contents>
                                            <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List1" refQuery="Retailer" rowsPerPage="1000">
                                                <noDataHandler>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <block>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                                                    </style>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </block>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </noDataHandler>
                                                <style>
                                                    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                                    <defaultStyles>
                                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                                    </defaultStyles>
                                                </style>
                                                <listColumns>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Region"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Region"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Retailer country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Retailer country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Retailer"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Retailer"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                </listColumns>
                                                <sortList>
                                                    <sortItem refDataItem="Retailer country"/>
                                                </sortList>
                                                <masterDetailLinks>
                                                    <masterDetailLink>
                                                        <masterContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                        </masterContext>
                                                        <detailContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Retailer country"/>
                                                        </detailContext>
                                                    </masterDetailLink>
                                                </masterDetailLinks>
                                            </list>
                                            <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List2" refQuery="Branch">
                                                <noDataHandler>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <block>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                                                    </style>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </block>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </noDataHandler>
                                                <style>
                                                    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                                    <defaultStyles>
                                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                                    </defaultStyles>
                                                </style>
                                                <listColumns>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                </listColumns>
                                                <sortList>
                                                    <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </sortList>
                                                <masterDetailLinks>
                                                    <masterDetailLink>
                                                        <masterContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                        </masterContext>
                                                        <detailContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                        </detailContext>
                                                    </masterDetailLink>
                                                </masterDetailLinks>
                                            </list>
                                            <list horizontalPagination="true" name="List3" refQuery="Staff" rowsPerPage="1000">
                                                <noDataHandler>
                                                    <contents>
                                                        <block>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <staticValue>No Data Available</staticValue>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                    <style>
                                                                        <CSS value="padding:10px 18px;"/>
                                                                    </style>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </block>
                                                    </contents>
                                                </noDataHandler>
                                                <style>
                                                    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse"/>
                                                    <defaultStyles>
                                                        <defaultStyle refStyle="ls"/>
                                                    </defaultStyles>
                                                </style>
                                                <listColumns>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Sales region"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Sales region"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="City"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="Last name"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                    <listColumn>
                                                        <listColumnTitle>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lt"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemLabel refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnTitle>
                                                        <listColumnBody>
                                                            <style>
                                                                <defaultStyles>
                                                                    <defaultStyle refStyle="lc"/>
                                                                </defaultStyles>
                                                            </style>
                                                            <contents>
                                                                <textItem>
                                                                    <dataSource>
                                                                        <dataItemValue refDataItem="First name"/>
                                                                    </dataSource>
                                                                </textItem>
                                                            </contents>
                                                        </listColumnBody>
                                                    </listColumn>
                                                </listColumns>
                                                <sortList>
                                                    <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </sortList>
                                                <masterDetailLinks>
                                                    <masterDetailLink>
                                                        <masterContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                        </masterContext>
                                                        <detailContext>
                                                            <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                        </detailContext>
                                                    </masterDetailLink>
                                                </masterDetailLinks>
                                            </list>
                                        </contents>
                                        <repeaterGroups>
                                            <repeaterGroup refDataItem="Country">
                                                <sortList>
                                                    <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                                                </sortList>
                                            </repeaterGroup>
                                        </repeaterGroups>
                                    </repeater>
                                </contents>
                            </block>
                        </contents>
                    </pageBody>
                </page>
            </reportPages>
        </layout>
    </layouts>
    <XMLAttributes>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_CreateExtendedDataItems" value="true"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_modelModificationTime" value="2015-11-25T21:38:24.820Z"/>
        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="listSeparator" value=","/>
    </XMLAttributes>
    <modelPath>/content/folder[@name=&apos;Samples&apos;]/folder[@name=&apos;Models&apos;]/package[@name=&apos;GO sales (query)&apos;]/model[@name=&apos;model&apos;]</modelPath>
    <queries>
        <query name="BranchCountry">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="RetailerCountry">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="StaffCountry">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query4">
            <source>

                <queryOperation name="Union1">
                    <queryRefs>
                        <queryRef refQuery="BranchCountry"/>
                        <queryRef refQuery="RetailerCountry"/>
                    </queryRefs>
                    <projectionList autoGenerated="true">
                        <queryItem name="Country"/>
                    </projectionList>
                </queryOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem name="Country">
                    <expression>[Union1].[Country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="country">
            <source>

                <queryOperation name="Union2">
                    <queryRefs>
                        <queryRef refQuery="Query4"/>
                        <queryRef refQuery="StaffCountry"/>
                    </queryRefs>
                    <projectionList autoGenerated="true">
                        <queryItem name="Country"/>
                    </projectionList>
                </queryOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem name="Country" aggregate="none" sort="ascending">
                    <expression>[Union2].[Country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="email">
            <source>

                <sqlQuery name="SQL1" dataSource="great_outdoors_sales">
                    <sqlText>select &apos;Australia&apos; as country
, &apos;email@domain.com&apos; as email

union select &apos;Austria&apos; as country
, &apos;email@domain.com&apos; as email</sqlText>
                    <mdProjectedItems>
                        <mdProjectedItem name="country"/>
                        <mdProjectedItem name="email"/>
                    </mdProjectedItems>
                </sqlQuery>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem name="country">
                    <expression>[SQL1].[country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem name="email">
                    <expression>[SQL1].[email]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query2">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Branch].[City]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Year] = 2013</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="Branch">
            <source>
                <joinOperation>
                    <joinOperands>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="Query2"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="country"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                    </joinOperands>
                    <joinFilter>
                        <filterExpression>[Query2].[Country] = [country].[Country]</filterExpression>
                    </joinFilter>
                </joinOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Query2].[Country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Query2].[City]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query1">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Region">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Region]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Retailer country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Retailer">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Year] = 2013</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="Retailer">
            <source>
                <joinOperation>
                    <joinOperands>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="Query1"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="country"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                    </joinOperands>
                    <joinFilter>
                        <filterExpression>[Query1].[Retailer country] = [country].[Country]</filterExpression>
                    </joinFilter>
                </joinOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Region">
                    <expression>[Query1].[Region]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Retailer country">
                    <expression>[Query1].[Retailer country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Retailer">
                    <expression>[Query1].[Retailer]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
        <query name="Query3">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Country]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Sales region">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Sales region]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[City]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[Last name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Sales (query)].[Sales staff].[First name]</expression>
                    <XMLAttributes>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataType" value="3"/>
                        <XMLAttribute output="no" name="RS_dataUsage" value="0"/>
                    </XMLAttributes>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
            <detailFilters>
                <detailFilter>
                    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Time].[Year] = 2013</filterExpression>
                </detailFilter>
            </detailFilters>
        </query>
        <query name="Staff">
            <source>

                <joinOperation>
                    <joinOperands>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="Query3"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                        <joinOperand cardinality="1:1">
                            <queryRef refQuery="country"/>
                        </joinOperand>
                    </joinOperands>
                    <joinFilter>
                        <filterExpression>[Query3].[Country] = [country].[Country]</filterExpression>
                    </joinFilter>
                </joinOperation>
            </source>
            <selection>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Country">
                    <expression>[Query3].[Country]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Sales region">
                    <expression>[Query3].[Sales region]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="City">
                    <expression>[Query3].[City]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="Last name">
                    <expression>[Query3].[Last name]</expression>
                </dataItem>
                <dataItem aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none" name="First name">
                    <expression>[Query3].[First name]</expression>
                </dataItem>
            </selection>
        </query>
    </queries>
    <reportName>burst</reportName>
    <burst refQuery="country">
        <burstGroups>
            <burstGroup refDataItem="Country">
                <sortList>
                    <sortItem refDataItem="Country"/>
                </sortList>
            </burstGroup>
        </burstGroups>
        <burstLabel refDataItem="Country"/>
        <burstRecipient refQuery="email" refDataItem="email">
            <masterDetailLinks>
                <masterDetailLink>
                    <masterContext>
                        <dataItemContext refDataItem="Country"/>
                    </masterContext>
                    <detailContext>
                        <dataItemContext refDataItem="country"/>
                    </detailContext>
                </masterDetailLink>
            </masterDetailLinks>
        </burstRecipient>
    </burst>
</report>
```

Comment: i have set my bursting report successfully following the link i sent earlier.  The only issue now is i dont see anywereh to set the file and email subject dynamically. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_cr_rptstd_modrep_set_burst_options.html#cr_rptstd_modrep_set_burst_options   The instruction you sent is it for cognos analytics ? ( version 11). i have heard that different version have very different bursting usage. What is 'repeater'?

Comment: Yes, this is for Cognos Analytics.  You can tell by the report schema version and report style in the report spec I provided.  The subject is defined in the schedule.  If by "dynamically" you mean you want to update the subject based on data, I think Cognos doesn't do that.  A *Repeater* is a data container (just like a *List*).  Bursting in Cognos 11.0.x is exactly the same as in 10.2.x.

Comment: thank you. I haven't tried repeater but i have set the report with bursting. It's unfortunate that they dont allow subject to be flexible as recipients

Comment: hi dougp, i saw people use script in cognos . I wnat to explore if we can use backend script to set the subject dynamic. Do yoh know where to write script? I dont see options @dougp